# Domain Monotonicity - Neumann eigenvalue problem (Edit)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, examples-counterexamples, spectral-theory

Related to the question : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242136/why-m-1-subset-m-2-not-rightarrow-n-m-1-lambda-leq-n-m-2-lambda

The Neumann eigenvalues of the rectangle with sides $a$ and $b$ are $$\nu_{k,l}=\frac{(\pi k)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(\pi l)^2}{b^2},$$ with $k,l \in \mathbb{N}_0$. So assuming that $a>b$, the first $3$ eigenvalues are $\nu_1=0$, $\nu_2=\frac{\pi^2}{a^2}$, and $\nu_3 = \frac{\pi^2}{b^2}.$ We pick $1 < a < \sqrt{2}$, and choose $b>0$ sufficiently small, so that the rectanglecan be place inside the unit squre. For the unit squre, the first $3$ Neumann eigenvalues are $\nu_1 ' = 0$, $\nu_2 ' = \pi^2$, and $\nu_3 ' = \pi^2$. Since $a>1$, we have $\nu_2 < \nu_2 '$, which could not happen if domain monotonicity were true.

Does this example work? If so, since the spectrum of the rectangle is the same as Dirichlet condition, why it is a counterexample for NBC but not for DBC **(explanation in details please)**

Comment: This is the standard example (see Christian Remlings post in the linked question). The spectrum for the Neumann and Dirichlet problems are not the same. The Dirichlet eigenvalue problem does not have 0 in the spectrum. With this information, try to prove the non-monotonicity, and see how it fails. By the way, good work if you found the counter example by yourself!

Comment: Hello @mickep, I am blocked on this problem for a while. Could you explain to me in details your answer? I am not quite sure how to do it

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT YELL

Comment: Sorry for not writing $k\neq 0$ and $l\neq 0$ (which, of course was what I meant). Glad you got a clear answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mickep observes in the comments, the spectra are *not* the same! The Dirichlet spectrum is
$$ \lambda_{kl} = \bigg(\frac{\pi k}{a}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\frac{\pi l}{b}\bigg)^2,\ k,l = 1,2,3,\ldots $$
while the Neumann spectrum is
$$ \nu_{kl} = \bigg(\frac{\pi k}{a}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\frac{\pi l}{b}\bigg)^2,\ k,l = 0,1,2,3,\ldots $$
The intuition is that the Neumann spectrum explicitly "hears" the individual side lengths $a,b$, while in the Dirichlet spectrum the two are muddled together. This is the idea behind the counterexample given in Christian Remling's answer to your MathOverflow question, where given a rectangle you can create a smaller rectangle with a longer side that embeds.

Comment: Your answer are always good, thank you! I understand my mistake. I thought the only points different of Dirichlet spectrum was $(k,l)=(0,0)$, but it is silly.